# Installing Yesod

Tags: cabal, yesod

While installing Yesod on OSX Mavericks, with XCode5 and the clang wrapper, I am bombarded by this error:

```
Network/Wai/Middleware/RequestLogger.hs:166:1:
parse error on input `*'
Failed to install wai-extra-1.3.4.5
Updating documentation index
/Users/alexanderventura/Library/Haskell/doc/index.html
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
wai-extra-1.3.4.5 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Any idea as to why that would happen? I have been trying to install Yesod for hours with no success!

**Update**

After installing gcc4.8 and using it instead of the clang, I was able to get rid of this issue.

Unfortunately, I encountered another issue

```
lookupSymbol failed in relocateSection (relocate external)
/Users/alexanderventura/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/http-attoparsec-0.1.0/lib/HShttp-     attoparsec-0.1.0.o: unknown symbol `_httpzmtypeszm0zi8zi2_NetworkziHTTPziTypesziHeader_ByteRangeSuffix_con_info'
ghc: unable to load package `http-attoparsec-0.1.0'
Failed to install yesod-core-1.2.4.2
```

Any ideas as to what may be happening? Installing Yesod has been torture!

Comment: After looking at the source code for RequestLogger.hs in Github, https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/blob/master/wai-extra/Network/Wai/Middleware/RequestLogger.hs, I believe this has something to do with bad preprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling the Haskell Platform and updating cabal again seem to have done it.